# How to change a csv file into raster?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, geospatial, raster

I have been using this code to change a CSV into Raster. My data frame consists of carbon data , latitude and longitude. How to change it into raster and plot it?

```
library(sp)  # vector data
library(raster)  # raster data
library(rgdal)  # input/output, 
library(rgeos)  # geometry ops
library(spdep)  # spatial dependence

carbonstock<-foresta
head(carbonstock)

data<-data.frame(carbonstock$Longitude,carbonstock$Latitude,carbonstock$Carbon)

# points from scratch

coords = cbind(carbonstock$Latitude, carbonstock$Longitude)
sp = SpatialPoints(coords)

# make spatial data frame

spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords, data)
spdf = SpatialPointsDataFrame(sp, data)

# promote data frame to spatial
coordinates(data) = cbind(carbonstock$Latitude, carbonstock$Longitude)
coordinates(data) = ~lon + lat

# back to data
as.data.frame(data)
plot(data,)

dfr <- rasterFromXYZ(data)  #Convert first two columns as lon-lat and third as value               
plot(dfr)
dfr     

# create spatial points data frame
spg <- data
x<-carbonstock$Latitude
y<-carbonstock$Longitude
coordinates(spg) <- ~ x + y

# coerce to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
gridded(spg) <- TRUE

# coerce to raster
rasterDF <- raster(spg)
```

Comment: The code looks OK. What errors are you getting?